# wix button redirect using wixlocation.to

Tags: javascript, velo

I don't know if people use wix here but you all know javascript I guess :)

I created a profile page with a button linking to the create a profile page.

here is the code for the profile page..

```
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

import wixData from 'wix-data';

import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

$w.onReady(function () {

  let user = wixUsers.currentUser;

  let userId = user.id;

  let isLoggedIn = user.loggedIn; // true

  user.getEmail()

    .then((email) => {

      let userEmail = email;

      $w("#emailAddress").value = userEmail;

    });

  $w("#createProfileButton").onClick(() => {

    let toInsert = {

      "firstName": $w("#firstName").value,

      "lastName": $w("#lastName").value,

      "emailAddress": $w("#emailAddress").value,

    };

    wixData.insert("Members", toInsert)

      .then(() => {

        wixLocation.to("/account/my-profile");

      })

      .catch((err) => {

        let errorMsg = err;

        $w("#error").show();

      });

  });

});
```

the problem is the create a profile button wont work. It wont redirect. It does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data inserted to the collection?

I would start debugging by trying to simply call directly to:

wixLocation.to("/account/my-profile");

If it works maybe the error is somewhere in the insertion.